# UIImage resize and crop to fit

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, image-resizing

I read a lot, also here, but couldn't find a simple way to do it:
In objective c -
I have a big UIImage and a small UIImageView. I want to programmatically shrink the content of a UIImage just enough to fit the smaller dimension within the UIImageView. The larger dimension will be cropped, and the result will be the maximum I can get from an image without changing the proportion.

can you please help me?

Comment: Do you want to recalculate a new image or just plug the image in to your imageView and have it displayed correctly?

Comment: just plug it to the imageView.

Comment: then give Ahti's answer a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the View I want to embed the image into I used this code:

```
int xImage=image.size.width;
int xButton=self.frame.size.width;
double ratio=xButton/xImage;
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:ratio orientation:image.imageOrientation] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:ratio orientation:image.imageOrientation] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

this solved it.
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill was not enough.

Answer (score 2):

To display the image in a fitting way, you really just set the `imageView.image` property to your image, and the adjust the `imageView.contentMode` to your liking. From what you wrote i think `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` is what you are looking for, but play around with it to see what fits you best.

If you want to save the image on the device and are **absolutely** sure that you will never need a bigger version of the image, then downscaling it would of course save some disk space and be a reasonable thing to do.
You would probably do this via CoreGraphics. You set up a bitmap context with the desired dimensions and tell the image to draw itself in there, and then get the result image back.
That would, however, be a pretty expensive thing to do performance-wise, and you should only ever do it once for every image you need to shrink. Also you do not want to do this on your main thread either, but GCD makes that very easy.